# Checking to see if a function is shell built in on linux mint

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint

On my exam I had this question:

Indicate which commands are NOT built-in.

a.
info

b.
help

c.
echo

d.
man

e.
ls

f.
cd

g.
pwd

h.
mv

And i said that the not built in are info, man, ls and mv, but I didn't get the full points, I seem to have missed some.
To check if a function is built in I used "type". Can someone tell me what I missed and what is the corect method to check this?

Comment: I think you were entirely correct. Using Bash (the default shell on Linux Mint), you can force the use of a builtin by running `builtin <command>`, and using that technique with your list of commands will yield `not a shell builtin` for `info`, `man`, `ls`, and `mv`.

Comment: Was the question about `bash` explicitly or about `sh`?  On some systems `sh` is really `bash`, but on others it is `dash`.  `help` is not a built-in for `dash`.  See [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725296/4154375).

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that on linux mint /bin/sh is [tag:dash-shell]. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would have given the same answer: info, man, ls and mv are not built-in, the rest are built-in. I do **not** think this is likely to be different on different versions of bash or different Linux distributions (assuming you are using bash and not another shell).

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
4.4.23(1)-release
$ type info
info is /usr/bin/info
$ type help
help is a shell builtin
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type man
man is /usr/bin/man
$ type ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ type mv
mv is /usr/bin/mv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BScXJMdgjPsw1KNjT30@Jq6SyIFUhMy8tH8LKSM0pgLBAqiGs3MQ8CCOnGEInp0DognIoI7fs/38A)

I see several possibilities:

- You made an error when filling out the form (e.g. ticked the wrong box)
- Your teacher made an error when checking your answers
- The question was about a shell other than bash. Maybe echo is not built-in in some shells or maybe ls is a built-in
- The question is somewhat poorly worded and is asking which commands are available as external executables (even if they are shadowed by built-ins). In my experiments this adds echo, pwd and [surprisingly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/458992) cd

```
$ type -P help
$ type -P echo
/usr/bin/echo
$ type -P cd
/usr/bin/cd
$ type -P pwd
/usr/bin/pwd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6SyIFVBN0AhIzWngAvGSU3OyIdzklPgzILylP//AQ)

As suggested by [@pjh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76395654/checking-to-see-if-a-function-is-shell-built-in-on-linux-mint#comment134714632_76395654) I have checked what is the default shell on linux mint. Turns out it is [dash-shell](/questions/tagged/dash-shell) rather than [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) Note: at the time of writing the question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
$ file /bin/sh
/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash
```

It turns out that dash unhelpful (help: not found)

```
$ type info
info is /usr/bin/info
$ type help
help: not found
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type man
man is /usr/bin/man
$ type ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ type mv
mv is /usr/bin/mv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvj/v6SyIFUhMy8tnwvMykjNKYCwUpMzoGK5iXkQRk4xhE5OgdAF5VBGbtn//wA)

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, the question is ambiguous. Is pwd builtin? Yes... also no, because /bin/pwd as a non-builtin exists. Same for echo, it's builtin, but also /bin/echo which is not builtin exists. So when they say is echo NOT builtin... well when it comes to /bin/echo is not builtin, so... I would have asked instead, which of these commands do not have  a builtin version.

Sometimes you will get the non-builtin without giving it much thought. For example
`exec echo Hello World`

executes one command  ... "echo" and it's not the builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged the question with *bash*, I assume that you want to know a bash solution.

The solution which immediately springs to mind is to use `type`, for instance

```
type cd
```

which should answer: *cd is a shell builtin*

However, there is a caveat. If someone would have overridden the command, for instance by

```
alias cd='echo x'
```

you would now get as answer: *cd is aliased to 'echo x'*

So, do get a more reliable solution, you would do a

```
type -a cd
```

and this would then display

> cd is aliased to 'echo x'

> cd is a shell builtin

> cd is /usr/bin/cd

However, this is still not safe. What if someone would have redefined the `type` command, i.e.

```
alias type='echo y'
```

To catch this case as well, the final recommended solution would be to use

```
'type' -a cd
```

The quotes would tell bash to use the builtin *type* command.